# Web API Binding Always Null when Premitive type and application/x-www-form-urlencoded used

Tags: asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Following is default method from Web API template. Most of the time I am using application/json as Content-Type but when I used application/x-www-form-urlencoded and pass data to api as value=test. It is failed to recognize or bind.

```
public void Post([FromBody]string value)
{
}
```

This thing work when I pass value as =test instead of value=test but if I pass same thing to MVC controller it is working.

If I do something like this then it is working.

```
public class TestModel
{
   public string value {get;set;}
}

public void Post([FromBody]TestModel model)
{
}
```

What is issue with first method and why it is not working ? Why it is working with MVC Controller or Binding and not with Web API Parameter Binding ?

Answer (score 0):

When you use form data (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) put [FormForm] instead of [FromBody].

Comment: Are you sure this is related to ASP.net Web API / Web API 2 and not related to ASP.net core ?

Comment: oh, sorry, you are right. that was for  core. for previous versions, you have 2 options: you should either wrap your primitive type into complex one or send variables in body without key. ref: check section 'Sending simple types' here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1 i always wrapped them into complex type as it also gives you benefit of model validation.